# Select a record just if the one before it has a lower value filtered by month

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a very complicated answer about my question here:

[Select a record just if the one before it has a lower value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18801262/select-a-record-just-if-the-one-before-it-has-a-lower-value)

about 3 weeks ago.

now I'm troubled with altering this query.

so this is the final version of this query right now:

```
SELECT  a.ID, DATE_FORMAT(a.Time,'%d/%m/%y') AS T, a.SerialNumber, 
    b.Remain_Toner_Black BeforeCount,
    a.Remain_Toner_Black AfterCount
FROM    
    (
        SELECT  a.ID, 
                a.Time, 
                a.SerialNumber, 
                a.Remain_Toner_Black,
                (
                    SELECT  COUNT(*)
                    FROM    Reports c
                    WHERE   c.SerialNumber = a.SerialNumber AND
                            c.ID <= a.ID) AS RowNumber
        FROM    Reports a
    ) a
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT  a.ID, 
                a.Time, 
                a.SerialNumber, 
                a.Remain_Toner_Black,
                (
                    SELECT  COUNT(*)
                    FROM    Reports c
                    WHERE   c.SerialNumber = a.SerialNumber AND
                            c.ID <= a.ID) AS RowNumber
        FROM    Reports a
    ) b ON a.SerialNumber = b.SerialNumber AND
            a.RowNumber = b.RowNumber + 1
WHERE b.Remain_Toner_Black < a.Remain_Toner_Black AND b.Remain_Toner_Black >= 0
```

and it takes about **0.0002** sec to accomplish.

what I want is to edit the last line of this query so it would be:

```
WHERE month(a.Time) = ".$i." AND b.Remain_Toner_Black < a.Remain_Toner_Black AND b.Remain_Toner_Black >= 0
```

but then, the query takes about **6.9047** sec to accomplish.

How can I add this:
**month(a.Time) = ".$i."**
to the query in the most time efficient way?

Comment: of course it will take time. you are applying a filter condition, try applying index on a.time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into this, the following way is possibly a quicker way of doing the basic select than you are already using:-

```
SELECT AfterSub.ID, 
    AfterSub.SerialNumber, 
    BeforeSub.Remain_Toner_Black BeforeCount,
    AfterSub.Remain_Toner_Black AfterCount
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, SerialNumber, Remain_Toner_Black, @Counter1:=@Counter1+1 AS SeqCnt
    FROM TableName
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Counter1:=0) Sub1
    ORDER BY SerialNumber, ID
) AfterSub
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ID, SerialNumber, Remain_Toner_Black, @Counter2:=@Counter2+1 AS SeqCnt
    FROM TableName
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Counter2:=1) Sub2
    ORDER BY SerialNumber, ID
) BeforeSub
ON BeforeSub.SerialNumber = AfterSub.SerialNumber
AND BeforeSub.SeqCnt = AfterSub.SeqCnt
WHERE   AfterSub.Remain_Toner_Black > BeforeSub.Remain_Toner_Black
ORDER BY AfterSub.SerialNumber, AfterSub.ID
```

The problem with checking the month here is that the following item could be in a different month, and this is relying on a count.

You could try:-

```
SELECT AfterSub.ID, 
    AfterSub.SerialNumber, 
    BeforeSub.Remain_Toner_Black BeforeCount,
    AfterSub.Remain_Toner_Black AfterCount
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, SerialNumber, Remain_Toner_Black, @Counter1:=@Counter1+1 AS SeqCnt
    FROM TableName
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Counter1:=0) Sub1
    ORDER BY SerialNumber, ID
) AfterSub
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ID, SerialNumber, Remain_Toner_Black, @Counter2:=@Counter2+1 AS SeqCnt
    FROM TableName
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Counter2:=1) Sub2
    ORDER BY SerialNumber, ID
) BeforeSub
ON BeforeSub.SerialNumber = AfterSub.SerialNumber
AND BeforeSub.SeqCnt = AfterSub.SeqCnt
AND AfterSub.Remain_Toner_Black > BeforeSub.Remain_Toner_Black
WHERE month(BeforeSub.Time) = ".$i." 
ORDER BY AfterSub.SerialNumber, AfterSub.ID
```

but this won't use an index (but the number of rows I would hope is low so I would hope not an issue).

You could possibly do the select to get the sequence numbers, then only check the items for that month, before joining to the next month:-

```
SELECT AfterSub.ID, 
    AfterSub.SerialNumber, 
    BeforeSub.Remain_Toner_Black BeforeCount,
    AfterSub.Remain_Toner_Black AfterCount
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, SerialNumber, Remain_Toner_Black, @Counter1:=@Counter1+1 AS SeqCnt
    FROM TableName
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Counter1:=0) Sub1
    ORDER BY SerialNumber, ID
) AfterSub
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ID, SerialNumber, Remain_Toner_Black, SeqCnt
    FROM
    (
        SELECT ID, SerialNumber, Remain_Toner_Black, `Time`, @Counter2:=@Counter2+1 AS SeqCnt
        FROM TableName
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Counter2:=1) Sub2
        ORDER BY SerialNumber, ID
    ) BeforeSub
    WHERE month(BeforeSub.Time) = ".$i." 
) BeforeSub
ON BeforeSub.SerialNumber = AfterSub.SerialNumber
AND BeforeSub.SeqCnt = AfterSub.SeqCnt
AND AfterSub.Remain_Toner_Black > BeforeSub.Remain_Toner_Black
ORDER BY AfterSub.SerialNumber, AfterSub.ID
```

(note, neither of the last 2 selects are tested)

EDIT

Adding a check for year / month to the 2 subselects. However as the date is being formatted to do this check I am not sure the index will be useful:-

```
SELECT AfterSub.ID, 
    AfterSub.SerialNumber, 
    BeforeSub.Remain_Toner_Black BeforeCount,
    AfterSub.Remain_Toner_Black AfterCount
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, SerialNumber, Remain_Toner_Black, @Counter1:=@Counter1+1 AS SeqCnt
    FROM TableName
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Counter1:=0) Sub1
    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`Time`,'%Y %m') >= '2013 01' 
    ORDER BY SerialNumber, ID
) AfterSub
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ID, SerialNumber, Remain_Toner_Black, `Time`, @Counter2:=@Counter2+1 AS SeqCnt
    FROM TableName
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Counter2:=1) Sub2
    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`Time`,'%Y %m') = '2013 01' 
    ORDER BY SerialNumber, ID
) BeforeSub
ON BeforeSub.SerialNumber = AfterSub.SerialNumber
AND BeforeSub.SeqCnt = AfterSub.SeqCnt
AND AfterSub.Remain_Toner_Black > BeforeSub.Remain_Toner_Black
ORDER BY AfterSub.SerialNumber, AfterSub.ID
```

Using a date in the subselects (which means working out the last day of the month) might be more efficient:-

```
SELECT AfterSub.ID, 
    AfterSub.SerialNumber, 
    BeforeSub.Remain_Toner_Black BeforeCount,
    AfterSub.Remain_Toner_Black AfterCount
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, SerialNumber, Remain_Toner_Black, @Counter1:=@Counter1+1 AS SeqCnt
    FROM TableName
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Counter1:=0) Sub1
    WHERE `Time` >= '2013-01-01' 
    ORDER BY SerialNumber, ID
) AfterSub
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ID, SerialNumber, Remain_Toner_Black, `Time`, @Counter2:=@Counter2+1 AS SeqCnt
    FROM TableName
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Counter2:=1) Sub2
    WHERE `Time` BETWEEN '2013-01-31' AND '2013-01-31'
    ORDER BY SerialNumber, ID
) BeforeSub
ON BeforeSub.SerialNumber = AfterSub.SerialNumber
AND BeforeSub.SeqCnt = AfterSub.SeqCnt
AND AfterSub.Remain_Toner_Black > BeforeSub.Remain_Toner_Black
ORDER BY AfterSub.SerialNumber, AfterSub.ID
```

Comment: "but the number of rows I would hope is low so I would hope not an issue" the problem is that it's about to be millions of rows

Comment: Ouch. Suspect your original query (without the date check) will struggle as well. Are you just checking against a month, or are you also wanting to check against a month / year? If you are checking against a month / year then it should be possible to code it up.

Comment: I'm planning to check against a month and a year. I would really appreciate if you do

Comment: Added a couple more suggestions (again, afraid not tested)

Answer (score 0):

Please place index on A.time and use this

```
SELECT  a.ID, DATE_FORMAT(a.Time,'%d/%m/%y') AS T, a.SerialNumber, 
    b.Remain_Toner_Black BeforeCount,
    a.Remain_Toner_Black AfterCount
FROM    
    (
        SELECT  a.ID, 
                a.Time, 
                a.SerialNumber, 
                a.Remain_Toner_Black,
                month(a.time) as Month
                (
                    SELECT  COUNT(*)
                    FROM    Reports c
                    WHERE   c.SerialNumber = a.SerialNumber AND
                            c.ID <= a.ID) AS RowNumber
        FROM    Reports a
    ) a
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT  a.ID, 
                a.Time, 
                a.SerialNumber, 
                a.Remain_Toner_Black,
                (
                    SELECT  COUNT(*)
                    FROM    Reports c
                    WHERE   c.SerialNumber = a.SerialNumber AND
                            c.ID <= a.ID) AS RowNumber
        FROM    Reports a
    ) b ON a.SerialNumber = b.SerialNumber AND
            a.RowNumber = b.RowNumber + 1
WHERE a.month = ".$i." AND b.Remain_Toner_Black < a.Remain_Toner_Black AND b.Remain_Toner_Black >= 0`
```

Comment: can someone tell me how to post code here. I struggle every time :((((

Comment: just do a couple of spaces with your keyboard

Comment: @GuyMessika please see the answer now. it should give better performance, as using function(any build in ) is not advised.

Comment: How can I index a datetime field on mysql? I've got this: 
Keyname: Time, Type: BTREE, Unique: No, Packed: No, Coulmn: Time ...

Comment: and where did a.month on the last WHERE in the query came from? you had just set month(a.time) as Month

Comment: Btree is clustered index , go for Hash

Comment: the calculation month(a.time)  you were doing on the run & i have calculated this value in inner query and compared the same in the where

Comment: i can't go to hash. hash is not supported by InnoDB storage engine. And I can't change the storage engine type

Comment: my current storage engine is MyISAM. How can I alter it to NDB or MEMORY using mysql?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that whether this answer will solve your problem or not, but i think if you append this condition month(a.Time) = ".$i." in both sub queries i.e. sub query 'a' and sub query 'b', it might help and improve the performance of your query.

Comment: I think the problem with this suggestion would be that he wants to test the following remaining toner. The following record could be on the next month, but I think from the description should still be included. But if the test is only added to the subselect for the 1st toner amount the sequence numbers would be out. Might be possible to add a check to the 2nd toner select that the month is >= $i but this would fail over December / January.