# How to create virtual columns with date interval from single column

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have this table **changes** in which I am storing changes from another table:

```
changes
----------------------------  
|id|  dat     |sid|  des   |  
----------------------------  
| 1|2015-12-08|  0| change1|  
| 2|2015-12-09|  0| change2|  
| 3|2015-12-10|  0| change3|  
| 4|2015-12-06|  1| change1|
```

Table contains date change in column **des** for specific **sid**. 
Respectively, every row stores the old value **des** valid to date in column **dat**.

**I need to create this output:**

```
result
-----------------------------------
|sid|   _from  |   _to    | des   |  
-----------------------------------  
|  0|     start|2015-12-08|change1|  
|  0|2015-12-08|2015-12-09|change2|  
|  0|2015-12-09|2015-12-10|change3|  
|  1|     start|2015-12-06|change1|
```

I am using this query:

```
SELECT   
 `m`.`sid`,  
 IFNULL((SELECT `s`.`dat`
  FROM `changes` `s`   
  WHERE ((`s`.`sid` = `m`.`sid`) AND (`s`.`dat` < `m`.`dat`))   
  ORDER BY `s`.`dat` desc LIMIT 1), 'start') AS `_from`,  
 `m`.`dat` AS `_to`,  
 `m`.`des`   
FROM `changes` `m`
```

Is there a better solution (in terms of the speed of query processing)?

Thank

Answer (score 0):

This query should do the job:

```
SELECT 
id,
IF(@prev_sid != sid OR @prev_dat IS NULL, 'start', @prev_dat) AS '_from',
dat AS '_to',
des,
@prev_sid := sid,
@prev_dat := dat
FROM changes c
, (SELECT @prev_sid := NULL, @prev_dat := NULL) var_init_subquery
ORDER BY sid, dat
```

An explanation of how this works can be found in my answer [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24036260/447489).

You can also read more about user defined variables in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html).

Comment: Supper, this is great solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT
    sid
  , IF(@sid_old = sid, dat, 'START')
  , dat AS _to
  , des
  , @sid_old := sid AS dummy
FROM changes
, (SELECT @sid_old := '') AS tmp
ORDER BY sid, dat;
```